# Differences when using print func in Swift and print command in console

Tags: swift, xcode

I printed the same string from code and in console, and it seems that the `\n` newline character is escaped differently.

1. Using print function in Swift code:

   ```
   print(myString)
   ```

output:

> "my String
>   and one more line"

2. Using print in console (or `po` same thing)

   ```
   print myString
   ```

output:

> "my String\nand one more line"

How can I get the same multiline string by using print in console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "problem" is merely that `lldb` is not Swift. So neither `po` nor `print` mean what you think they mean. Try this instead:

```
(lldb) po print("hey\nho")
```

Basically `po` is the same as `expr`; we are saying, "evaluate the following as a Swift expression." So we get Swift's native printing behavior.